# How to print only evens from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently learning to code. I have to create an array and then create a function that prints only the even numbers from the array. Here is what I currently have. I am at a loss on what to do. I am learning from Code Highschool. It is what my class is making us use.

Instructions from codehs:

Write a function called
function onlyEvens(arr)
That takes an array and returns an array with only the even numbers in the original array.
Then, you should print out the new list.

How do I get the code to only print the even numbers that are in the array?

```
function start(){
    var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    var evens = onlyEvens(arr);
   println(evens);
}

function onlyEvens(arr){


}
```

Comment: It sounds like you'll need to find out how to determine if a number is even.

Comment: Loop by evens?? Learn to use the modulus like your class probably taught you to use?

Comment: If you are going to learn to code , learning how to search the web for code related issues will be a big plus. This is probably isn't hard to research and you should be searching for information before asking questions here

Comment: @epascarello My class never taught me how to use the modulus. But I went and did more research on the searching i had already done and taught myself how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can use like this

```
start();
function start(){
    var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    var evens = onlyEvens(arr);
    console.log(evens);
}

function onlyEvens(arr){
  evenArr={};
for (var i = 0,j=0 ;i < arr.length; i++) {
   if(arr[i] % 2 === 0) { //
       evenArr[j] = arr[i];
       j++;
   }
}
  return evenArr;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n3jke25n/

Answer (score 0):

The operator you're looking for is the modulus operator.

For any integer variable `x`, if `x % 2 == 1`, `x` is odd.  On the other hand, if `x % 2 == 0`, `x` is even.

Thus, write an `if` statement that determines, using the modulus operator, whether the number in question is even; then, if it is, add it to the destination array.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a modulo in onlyEvens whilst cycling the array

```
    for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {

    if i%2==0 {
        console.log("is even:"+arr[i])
    }
}
```

Something like that, more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: if you are going to answer someone's homework assignment shouldn't you at least provide code that uses common best practices?

Comment: I consider myself spanked by your overlord mastery :)